# No option of 3200x1800 resolution on my virtualbox linux

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I just installed a xubuntu system on my virtualbox. I installed guest additions for virtualbox, but I do not have the option to resize the screen to 3200x1800, as i have a 4k res screen. Is 4k supported in virutalbox, and if so, how do i set my linux distro to 4k?
Thank you

Comment: You haven't said what release of Xubuntu, as HiDpi is a pretty new feature with Xubuntu (XFCE 4.14). It could also be a setting/restriction in your unnamed host system

Comment: I'm running the latest 18.04.3 version of xubuntu. As for my host system, I'm running it on Windows 10 Home version.

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04 (2018-April release) is two releases behind the latest, and uses XFCE 4.12.3 which has less HiDPI features than later releases, however for features and limits of your virtualbox you'll have to check with your version & else-where as it's a windows question (*some versions have fewer features and resolution is limited by settings, [vbox] graphics-driver used & extensions loaded on your host; windows 10*).